# How to structure a limited query in AirTable

Tags: rest, airtable

This is bringing back too much data, 
https://api.airtable.com/v0/MyAccoutNumber/Movies?&api_key=MyKey
How can I just have it bring back the film names for instance. I have tried putting in various changes into the query but either an error occurs or the very same amount of data returns?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fields` parameter to limit which fields are returned in the results. `fields` takes an URL-encoded array of field names or IDs.

For example, if you only want two fields called "Name" and "Year" returned in the results, the request would look like this:

`/v0/appId/tableName?fields%5B%5D=Name&fields%5B%5D=Year`

You can see [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) as a reference for URL-encoding arrays and objects. In this case, `jQuery.param({fields: ["Name", "Year"])` returns `fields%5B%5D=Name&fields%5B%5D=Year`.

Comment: Thank you, works great, how can I get back just one description of one movie from the airtable demo 'Favorite Movies'. I tried various codings it brings back error or all descriptions. fields%5BThe%20Godfather%5D=Description&api_key=key